# Problem with sudo dnf update on Fedora 38 (recently upgraded)

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, upgrade, x86

I've recently upgraded to Fedora 38 and when I try to `sudo dnf update`, I get the following error:

```
Problem: package libheif-freeworld-1.15.2-1.fc38.x86_64 requires libheif(x86-64) = 1.15.2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both libheif-1.16.1-1.fc38.x86_64 and libheif-1.15.2-1.fc38.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libheif-freeworld-1.15.2-1.fc38.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libheif-1.15.2-1.fc38.x86_64
==========================================================================================================================================
 Package                        Architecture                  Version                                Repository                      Size
==========================================================================================================================================
Skipping packages with conflicts:
(add '--best --allowerasing' to command line to force their upgrade):
 libheif                        x86_64                        1.16.1-1.fc38                          updates                        288 k

Transaction Summary
==========================================================================================================================================
Skip  1 Package

Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I've tried `dnf install libheif` from [Fedora_docs](https://fedora.pkgs.org/38/fedora-updates-x86_64/libheif-1.16.1-1.fc38.x86_64.rpm.html) but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libheif-freeworld` package has simply not yet been pushed to `rpmfusion-free-updates` repository at the time of writing. It's [still](https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/updates/testing/38/x86_64/l/) in `rpmfusion-free-updates-testing` and enabling that repository will let `dnf` resolve the dependencies and complete the transaction:

```
sudo dnf --enablerepo=rpmfusion-free-updates-testing update libheif
```

In fact, the RPM Fusion FAQ section has the above answer for [exactly this kind of issue](https://rpmfusion.org/FAQ#Broken_deps.2C_What_to_do_.3F).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something is wrong with your RPMFusion repo - `libheif-freeworld`. Maybe they haven't updated the package yet.

In the meantime you could update this way:

```
sudo dnf update --exclude='libheif*'
```

Comment: this works for now, I wonder when they'll update it

Comment: RPMFusion is a community project, so it's up to the package maintainer[s]. You may as well email them and alert to the fact that there's an update.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers did work and there's now an update for `libheif` when doing `sudo dnf update` I get the newly updated packages:

```
libheif        x86_64       1.16.1-1.fc38          updates           288 k
libheif-freeworld   x86_64      1.16.1-1.fc38  rpmfusion-free-updates 51 k
```

Mostly any issue similar to mind you would probably just have to wait for an update like [@Rathann](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/174468/rathannhttps://) & [@Artem S. Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov) said.